# How to create multiple rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to have this kind of structure in .htaccess. Is it possible?

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
  RewriteRule ^signup$ /signup.html [L]

  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
  RewriteRule ^signin$ /signin.html [L]

  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
  RewriteRule ^home$ /landing.html [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

For landing, signin, signup I want to request separate pages and for all other requests I need to request index.html page. Can I do that with .htaccess?

Comment: Other than some extra conditions your rules look fine. Any particular problem you're getting?

Comment: I could only access routes defined in .htaccess (/signup, /signin, /home) and  all other routes, its showing Internal server error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(signup|signin)/?$ $1.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ landing.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```